# glTranslatef Equivalent without it

Tags: c++, opengl

Ok so I'm hooking into a game to retrieve data from it and use it. I got as far as hooking text (via CallLists).

The game uses:

[image]

```
glNewlist()
glBegin(GL_QUADS)
glVertex2i(....);    //Stored the location of each char in the bitmap above..
glTexCoords2f(....); //Not sure what this is..
glEnd()
glEndList()

glCallList(876);   //Represents a single character in the above bitmap.
glLoadIdentity();   //Resets the matrix.
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE, GL_REPLACE);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SOURCE0_RGB, GL_TEXTURE);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SOURCE0_RGB, GL_PREVIOUS);
glTranslatef(336, 196, 0);  //Places it on screen somehow! :S? This is what I need to know.
glColor4ub(0, 0, 0, 255);  //Colours the text.
LoadIdentity();            //Resets the matrix and does the next character.
glCallList(877);           //Next char.
```

To render text to the screen. Is there a way I can figure out the coords of the text on the screen? I have access to all functions via Detours.

I'm not sure what the glTranslate did. How can I get the X and Y of the text?

I've used this to project the coords from glTranslate but it still projects it wrong. What do I pass to my WorldVector? It is just a struct with X, Y, Z. I've passed it the glTranslate coords but that doesn't work.

```
bool WorldToScreen(GLfloat &X, GLfloat &Y, Vector3D World, GLdouble* ModelViewMatrix, GLdouble* ProjectionMatrix)
{
    GLint ViewPort[4];
    GLdouble Screen[3];
    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, ViewPort);

    if(gluProject(World.X, World.Y, World.Z, ModelViewMatrix, ProjectionMatrix, ViewPort, &Screen[0], &Screen[1], &Screen[2]) == GL_TRUE)
    {
        X = Screen[0];
        Y = ViewPort[3] - Screen[1];
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: FYI, you're calling glVertex and glTexCoord in the wrong order (glVertex should always come last after other attributes). Until you fix it you will likely be confused and it won't work like you expect.

Comment: I'm not the one that calls that. That's the game's code. I'm caling the PrintF to render my text directly on top of theirs. My problem is that I'm trying to find the coordinates of theirs so I hooked all the functions you see above and that's the order it's called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That really depends, if you are drawing your text in orthographic mode, whatever you pass into glTranslatef is the actual screen coordinate, where if you are in perspective mode, you will have to pass them through the transformation pipeline to get the screen coordinates, I believe the function for doing this would be in the GLU library called gluProject, where gluUnProject would bring screen coordinates to world space

```
translate to world position 
translate to view position 
divide by W (Copy of Z) to get projection coordinates 
ScreenX = Px * ScreenWidth/2 + ScreenWidth/2 
ScreenY = -Py * ScreenWidth/2 + ScreenWidth/2
```

Comment: Ok well it's definitely not the first one since I've tried passing those as the actual screen coords. I've edited my post with the projection method I'm using.

Comment: Ok yes you are using perspective projection, which means you have to pass your coordinates through the pipeling to get the screen coordinates, the process this goes through is like this

I added code above to explain better
The resulting ScreenX and ScreenY will give you your screen coordinates, however gluProject will do this for you

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer but that didn't work. I don't have the coords to pass through the pipeline. It's using a call list: with this: http://i.imgur.com/IRFlg.png

And it renders each character one by one using glTranslate :S

Comment: I've edited my first post to clarify. I think you think I have the coords to project.

Comment: Holy cow, I didn't read that right the first time, I should have told you to simply use an orthographic projection, sorry I confused originally as to what you wanted to do, when rendering fonts you should always do so in orthographic (unless you are wanting to have your text on some 3D geometry. I recommend that you get the OpenGL red book, and learn a bit about OpenGL's different states and functions, but basically in an orthographic projection, your translation is done in screen coordinates

Comment: Ahh I figured it out :) I applied the transformations manually to each vertex in the call list and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of translating and calling your list in orthographic

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0.0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0.0, -1.0, 1.0);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(336.0f, 196.0f, 0.0f);
glColor4f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); //Red
glCallList(877); //Or whatever list you wish to call
```

At this point, you may want to have the width of the next character to write, and simply translate value to put your text directly to the right of it,

By the way, there is a great free to use library called FreeType 2 , Blizzard uses it for there games, as well as myself, the former of which gives it good credibility.

If I am still not answering your question be sure to let me know